# creating nested sequences in R

Tags: r, sequence, paste

I would like to create the following `vector` which consists of two nested `sequences`, plus the letters `a` and `b`:

```
desired.data <- c('a1b1', 'a1b2', 'a1b3', 'a2b1','a2b2', 'a2b3', 
                  'a3b1', 'a3b2', 'a3b3', 'a4b1','a4b2', 'a4b3', 
                  'a5b1', 'a5b2', 'a5b3')
```

I suspect this is a duplicate, but I have searched `Stack Overflow` for an hour without success.  Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution that may be more viable if the pattern in the strings is more complex than just two numbers and two characters

```
concat <- function(x) paste0('a', x[, 2], 'b', x[, 1])
concat(expand.grid(1:3, 1:5))
#[1] "a1b1" "a1b2" "a1b3" "a2b1" "a2b2" "a2b3" "a3b1" "a3b2" "a3b3" "a4b1" "a4b2" "a4b3" "a5b1" "a5b2" "a5b3"
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `paste0`, `rep` with its `each` argument, and rely on vector recycling:

```
paste0("a", rep(1:5, each = 3), "b", 1:3)
#[1] "a1b1" "a1b2" "a1b3" "a2b1" "a2b2" "a2b3" "a3b1" "a3b2" "a3b3" "a4b1" "a4b2" "a4b3" "a5b1" "a5b2" "a5b3"
```